# what's the difference between clusterApply() and parApply() in R?

Tags: r

I'm learning Apply Operations using Clusters recently. And I'm confused about the difference between

```
clusterApply(cl = NULL, x, fun, ...)
```

and

```
parApply(cl = NULL, X, MARGIN, FUN, ..., chunk.size = NULL)
```

what's the difference in the usage of above two?

according to the R,

`clusterApply` calls `fun` on the first node with arguments `x[[1]]` and ..., on the second node with `x[[2]]` and ..., and so on, recycling nodes as needed.
and `parApply()` is also for parallel function.

```
clusterApply(cl = NULL, x, fun, ...) 

parApply(cl = NULL, X, MARGIN, FUN, ..., chunk.size = NULL)
```

Answer (score -2):

In short, `parApply` is the parallel version of `apply` while
`clusterApply` apply a function to a list of arguments.
Example:

```
> clusterApply(cl, c(2:4), sum, 10)
[[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 13

[[3]]
[1] 14
```